# Wordpress show only shortcode without content

Tags: wordpress

How to show only the shortcode not contents of a post in wordpress?

Code I am using is:

```
<?php $post_content = get_the_content(); ?>
<?php if ( has_shortcode( $post_content, '360' ) ) {
    echo do_shortcode( $post_content );
} ?>
```

Now the result is post content together with shortcode generated code, how to show only the shortcode?

Answer (score 2):

use code like this

```
$post_content = get_the_content();
if ( has_shortcode( $post_content, '360' ) ) {
  echo do_shortcode("[360]");
}
```

Comment: Does not work, because there is more attributes for the shortcode. I successfully used the php strpos() and substr() functions to find the location of a shortcode, than grab it and display it in do_shortcode function. 

Code is: $beginningStr = strpos($post_content, '[360'); $endingStr = strpos($post_content, '"]'); $shortCode = substr($post_content, $beginningStr, $endingStr); echo do_shortcode($shortCode);